# My App Stops When I Try To Get An Int

Tags: java, android, parsing, int

I'm trying to make an app that accepts an input and automatically changes it to an int. However, when it tries to obtain an int, the app automatically stops. Below is the full code...

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{  

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            Button calculate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.calculateTip);
            calculate.setOnClickListener(this);

        }//end onCreate

    public void onClick(View v) {

            EditText money = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.bill);
            int bill = Integer.parseInt(money.getText().toString());
            money.setText("Event Processed");

    }//end onClick

    }//end MainActivity
```

Comment: what error do you get? can you post your XML as well?

Comment: Are you sure you're sending and integer and not a double?

Comment: What are the contents of the text field? And what is the LogCat output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the application is stopping because the value you are trying to parse is not really an integer. You should throw that code into a try catch.

ie:

```
    public void onClick(View v) {

       EditText money;
       try
       {
            money = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.bill);

             // This check makes sure that the EditText is returning the correct object.
            if(money != null)
            {
              int bill = Integer.parseInt(money.getText().toString());
              money.setText("Event Processed");
            }
       }
       catch(NumberFormatException e)
       {
       // If we get in here that means the inserted value was not an Integer. So do               something.
       //ie:
        money.setText("Please enter a value amount" );
        }
    }//end onClick
```

Regardless, you should have this code in a try catch to maintain data integrity.

Hopefully this helps!
Cheers.

Comment: Does it make a difference if you assign `money` inside the `onClick` method?  I am usually just assign xml references in the onCreate

Comment: I would usually have money as a global variable, and then assign it in the onCreate as well. With money as a global variable you can then set it from anywhere in your class such as the onClick. This code sample just shows you what you "could" do with the code you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the Object is an instance of EditText and that it isn't null?

Comment: should be no problem with .toString()